# Загрузка картинок из ссылки

Tags: java, android, imageview

Есть список, в каждом элементе должна быть картинка. 
Картинки в виде http ссылок.

Неужели нет способа подгрузить картинки в основном потоке, не заморачиваясь с созданием новых потоков?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно же есть! для этого можете воспользоваться библиотекой [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Необходимо добавить ее к проекту записью в градл файл:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Использовать очень просто

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: О, спаситель! ))

Answer (score 2):

Используйте библиотеки, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) или [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), они все сделают за вас

Comment: Ну и [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) для полноты ответа.

Comment: @katso, этой библиотекой не пользовался, не знаю, но благодарю за уточнение

Answer (score 0):

Да пожалуйста, хотите основной поток, юзайте)):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Только смысл морозить основной поток, приложение будет не юзабельным.